# What happen if KMnO4/H+ added to phenylethanoic acid oxidation?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

What happen if KMnO4/H+ added to phenylethanoic acid oxidation?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding KMnO4/H+ to any compound containing benzene ring oxidizes the aliphatic part to COOH so benzoic acid is formed.

Note:The aliphatic part should not be 3°.

Comment: Thanks, what about the the other product? I guess the -COOH ganna be HCOOH..... so benzoic acid + HCOOH?

Comment: probably forms CO2